# String memory address location

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory

I am looking at the sequential ordering of memory address location in string arrays. I wanted to also pipe out the values at each index in the array.

I have referenced the memory address location. The issue is the output. I cannot understand why the whole string would be printed from address index 0 when I am only referring to the one address index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char strings[] = "hello";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(strings) - 1; i++) {
        printf("Memory location of strings[%d] : %x - value is : %s\n",
               i, &strings[i], &strings[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which returns

```
Memory location of strings[0] : 61fe0a - value is : hello 
Memory location of strings[1] : 61fe0b - value is : ello 
Memory location of strings[2] : 61fe0c - value is : llo 
Memory location of strings[3] : 61fe0d - value is : lo
Memory location of strings[4] : 61fe0e - value is : o
```

Can you please help me to understand why each index is being printed sequentially when the expectation is something like -

```
Memory location of strings[0] : 61fe0a - value is : h
Memory location of strings[1] : 61fe0b - value is : e
Memory location of strings[2] : 61fe0c - value is : l
Memory location of strings[3] : 61fe0d - value is : l
Memory location of strings[4] : 61fe0e - value is : o
```

Comment: Aside: the practise of `i <= strlen(strings)-1;` is not only hard to read, but is an error waiting to happen if you do this with unsigned variables. Please use the idiomatic `i < strlen(strings);`

Comment: Because you use %s, everything until '\0' will be printed. Try %c instead

Comment: The correct format specifier to print a `void *` pointer is `%p`. And the pointer *must* be cast to `void *`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type (like using the `unsigned int` format `%x` to print a pointer) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: you print string so its prints from adders to end for string print %c you get the char

Comment: As @infinitezero: instead of `%s` and `&strings[i]` please use `%c` and `strings[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

The program behaves as expected: you pass `&strings[i]` for the `%s` format, which expected a pointer to a null terminated C string. `printf` outputs all the characters in `strings` starting from the index `i`.

If you mean to only output the character at index `i`, you should use the `%c` format specifier.

Also note that you should use `%p` to output a pointer value and cast the argument as `(void *).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = "hello";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("Memory location of string[%d]: %p - value is: %c\n",
               i, (void *)&string[i], string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *always* pass the address to one of the characters.

In the following, `string` is a pointer to the location of `a`.

```c
const char *string = "abc";
printf( "%s\n", string );
```

In the following, `string` is an array. But `printf` needs a pointer. Fortunately, an array automatically "degenerates" into a pointer to its first element when necessary.

```c
char string[] = "abc";
printf( "%s\n", string );
printf( "%s\n", &( string[0] ) );  // Same thing!
```

Normally, you pass a pointer point to the first character. But there's nothing wrong with passing a pointer to the second character. `printf %s` will print the character at that location and characters at subsequent locations until a NUL is encountered.

If you want to print a single character, use `%c`.

```c
char string[] = "abc";
printf( "%c\n", string[1] );       // b
```